# how do I get the slurm job id?

Tags: python, linux, bash, slurm, sbatch

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH -N 1      # nodes requested
#SBATCH -n 1      # tasks requested
#SBATCH -c 4      # cores requested
#SBATCH --mem=10  # memory in Mb
#SBATCH -o outfile  # send stdout to outfile
#SBATCH -e errfile  # send stderr to errfile
#SBATCH -t 0:01:00  # time requested in hour:minute:second

module load anaconda
python hello.py jobid
```

lets say I have this code and I want to send the jobid to python, how do you get the job id, so when I do

```
sbatch script.sh
Submitted batch job 10514
```

how do I get the number 10514 and pass it to python?

Comment: The shell script you posted does nothing but call a python script. If you simply `echo` a result it goes to `stdout` and you can catch it with `var = sys.argv[1]` in python as an example

Comment: can you be more specific on how I do that

Answer (score 10):

You can just read it from environment variable, slurm will set SLURM_JOB_ID for the batch script.

```bash
module load anaconda
python hello.py $SLURM_JOB_ID
```

For all the environment variables that are available in the batch script, you can find them here: [OUTPUT ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES](https://slurm.schedmd.com/sbatch.html#SECTION_OUTPUT-ENVIRONMENT-VARIABLES)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `squeue`. Following is the list of valid usage of `squeue`.

```bash
Usage: squeue [-A account] [--clusters names] [-i seconds] [--job jobid]
              [-n name] [-o format] [-p partitions] [--qos qos]
              [--reservation reservation] [--sort fields] [--start]
              [--step step_id] [-t states] [-u user_name] [--usage]
              [-L licenses] [-w nodes] [--federation] [--local] [--sibling]
          [-ahjlrsv]
```

I will show you how to do it with `squeue -u` which allows you to use your username. In my case my username is `s.1915438`.

Here I submit a job.

```bash
[s.1915438@cl2 ~]$ sbatch jupyter.sh 
Submitted batch job 38529784
```

```bash
[s.1915438@cl2 ~]$ squeue -u s.1915438
             JOBID PARTITION     NAME     USER ST       TIME  NODES NODELIST(REASON)
          38529784  gpu_v100 jupyter- s.191543  R       2:09      1 ccs2101
```

Here the job ID is 38529784. You can also use the `USER` variable as follows.

```bash
[s.1915438@cl2 ~]$ squeue -u $USER
             JOBID PARTITION     NAME     USER ST       TIME  NODES NODELIST(REASON)
          38529784  gpu_v100 jupyter- s.191543  R       0:47      1 ccs2101
```

If you `echo` the `USER` variable then you will see it outputs your username. This is particularly useful when you write scripts.

```bash
[s.1915438@cl2 ~]$ echo $USER
s.1915438
```

You can do the same if you know the job name using `squeue -n`.

To get this thing in Python you need to use the `os` library as follows.

```bash
>>> import os
>>> a=os.system("squeue -u $USER | tail -1| awk '{print $1}'")
38529793
```

Here tail is used to obtain the last row and `awk` [selects the column](https://askubuntu.com/a/161803/1230667) as per our requirement.
As an extra, if you want to cancel a job then use `scancel` as follows.

```bash
[s.1915438@cl2 ~]$ scancel 38529784
```

Sometimes `scancel` may take 5-10 seconds.

Comment: But this is how I can get the number after I submit a job, I want to pass the job number to the python file in the same bash script.

Comment: I think that is not possible. The job id is completely random. Alternatively, you can go for interactive sessions. Just use `salloc` to submit an interactive job. Run all you bash files using `srun` and then you can access the job ID using `squeue`.

Comment: normally you don't need the job ID. What is your application? Maybe we can find a way around it.

Comment: arr=(0.000001 0.00001 0.0001 0.001)
for lr in "${arr[@]}"  # First loop.
            do
                sbatch gbash.sh $l1 $l2 $l3 False 'SGD' $lr .2
            done
I have this for loop that does sbatch gbash.sh on different scenarios, gbash.sh  has the python file to run the code and I want to know the job id that gbash.sh  gets so I can find it later if I need to.

Comment: Its easy with an interactive session. You just need to allocate the resource using `salloc` and then run any bash file using `srun`. This way you can easily print the JOB ID.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH -N 1      # nodes requested
#SBATCH -n 1      # tasks requested
#SBATCH -c 4      # cores requested
#SBATCH --mem=10  # memory in Mb
#SBATCH -o outfile  # send stdout to outfile
#SBATCH -e errfile  # send stderr to errfile
#SBATCH -t 0:01:00  # time requested in hour:minute:second

ME=`basename "$0"`
echo "My slurm job id is $ME"
```

You can run this file as `sbatch script.sh`

In the outfile you will find:

`My slurm job id is 12345678`